# If/else in for loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

How do I stop all the data from appending to `data1`, if `eventName` equals a certain value. However, I would like the loop to continue if `eventName` does not equal a certain value.

```
for event in eventid:
    request2 = requests.get(f'https://www.punters.com.au/api/web/public/Odds/getOddsComparisonCacheable/?allowGet=true&APIKey=65d5a3e79fcd603b3845f0dc7c2437f0&eventId={event}&betType=FixedWin', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    json2 = request2.json()
    eventname = json2['eventName']
    for selection in json2['selections']:
        for price in selection['prices']:
            if price['bookmaker'] in ['BetEasy', 'Neds', 'Sportsbet'] and price['hasOdds']:
                data1.append((eventname, selection['name'], price.get('bookmaker'), price.get('odds', 0)))
```

Comment: `if eventname == 'certain value': break`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :

```
for event in eventid:
    request2 = requests.get(f'https://www.punters.com.au/api/web/public/Odds/getOddsComparisonCacheable/?allowGet=true&APIKey=65d5a3e79fcd603b3845f0dc7c2437f0&eventId={event}&betType=FixedWin', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    json2 = request2.json()
    eventname = json2['eventName']
    for selection in json2['selections']:
        for price in selection['prices']:
            if price['bookmaker'] in ['BetEasy', 'Neds', 'Sportsbet'] and price['hasOdds'] and eventname != "certain_value":
                data1.append((eventname, selection['name'], price.get('bookmaker'), price.get('odds', 0)))
```

Comment: May I know why ?

Comment: I've meant, it's not the best idea to perform check `len(json2['selections']) * len(selection['prices'])` amount of times instead of single validation  before.

Comment: He wants to continue with the loop. Using validation and  break outside will not serve the purpose.

Comment: First of all, he doesn't want to continue loop. Quote: However, I would like *the loop* to *continue if eventName **does not equal** a certain value*. And it's not an obligatory to use `break` if you don't want, it changes nothing. You launch useless loop iterations without any reason.

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement:

```
if eventname == 'ceratin value':
    break  # stops loop
```

If you want to just skip appending values, then use regular condition.

Comment: He said he does not want to append the data but wants to continue with the loop. You answer will break out of loop. Please confirm

Comment: @hpollock then enclose your internal loops with this condition.

Comment: @hpollock, do not use his answer, it's very bad solution

Comment: @OlvinRoght... Hope you got the answer. xD

Comment: @PrashantKumar, I surrender, you're too powerful developer to speak with.

Comment: @OlvinRoght. No you have too much ego to talk in a polite way and too much attitute to surrender.  We are all here to contribute. I answered what I understood. There was no need to raid like that. Anyways. Peace out

Comment: @PrashantKumar, I've warned you 2 times, what's wrong with your answer. You don't want to edit it and decided to start a discussion instead.

Comment: My answer was accepted and works for @hopollok. You were telling what you understood out of the question and I was telling my understanding.

Comment: @PrashantKumar, once again - if something works, it doesn't mean that it's 100% correct. You've just added one more condition inside nested loop. It means, that check will be executed lot of times. Normally you have to check this condition before loops started. You've done job, but with useless resource consumption.